# ColdFusion - Multiple Inserts - Track Number On Each Insert

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Working on our fire report system...

Tracking who is on trucks...
So Truck A, Truck B, Truck C

I can get the counts of total staff - but not for each truck... I'm a bit out of ideas...
using ColdFusion 8

This (vehicle ID Number) nvid stuff I know doesn't work - just counts total staff but not individual trucks.  Each individual truck has a unique ID and staff variable attached to it... The CFInserts work fine for total numbers but not each truck number.

Ideas on how to track numbers of staff on each truck? Thx...

```
   <cfset nvid = 0>

    <cfloop from="1" to="#st.recordcount#" index="i">

    <cfif IsDefined("form.checkbox1_#i#")>

    <cfoutput>

    <cfset newvid = "vid_"&#variables.i#> 
    <cfset newloginid = "checkbox1_"&#variables.i#> 

    <cfset vid = "#Evaluate(variables.newvid)#"> 



    <cfset nvid = nvid + 1>


    <cfset loginid = "#Evaluate(variables.newloginid)#"> 

    <br>
    NewVid - #newvid# and VID - #vid#
    <br>
    cfquery name="insert" datasource="fire_report">

    INSERT INTO stafflist (id, unitid, loginid)

    VALUES (#id#, #vid#, #loginid#); 

    /cfquery> 
    <br>
    <br>
    </cfoutput>

    </cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

Comment: Can you post your form code and the [ddl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language#CREATE_TABLE_statement) of the relevant db tables? Also, please update the tags to indicate your database type and version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Decided to check data after the insert..
It works and perhaps this  was the easiest way unless anyone has anything else simpler...

Basically - if the numbers don't add up on a group check - I cflocation it to delete the previous data inserted and force them to do it again...

```
        Check Data After Insert???

        <cfquery name="tcheck" datasource="fire_report">
        select * from stafflist
        order by unitid
        </cfquery>
        <br>


        <cfoutput query="tcheck" group=unitid>

        <cfset groupCount = 0>
        <cfoutput>
        #unitid#
        <cfset groupCount = groupCount + 1>
        </cfoutput>
        <br><br>Check vs Original
        <br>

        <cfquery name="ucheck" datasource="fire_report">
        select * from unit
        WHERE ID=#id# and unitid = #unitid#
        </cfquery>
        Original: <cfoutput>#ucheck.unitid# - #ucheck.numff# &nbsp;</cfoutput>


        GroupCount = #groupCount#
        <br><br><cfif ucheck.numff NEQ groupCount>

        Bad<br>
        <cflocation url="staff.cfm?id=#id#&src=del">
        <cfelse>All Good<br></cfif>
        </cfoutput>
```

Comment: There is almost certainly a more efficient method than an insert/delete. But it would help to see the <form> code. As an aside, the SQL above is vulnerable to sql injection. Always use [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at your data model.  I suspect that in real life the people assigned to each truck can change over time.  There is nothing in your code sample to indicate you have thought about that.

For your specific question on counting people per truck, something like this would work.

```
select TruckName, count(*) PeoplePerTruck
from YourTruckTable join stafflist on TruckId = UnitId
group by TruckName
```

Comment: Its for reporting after the fact of who was on the truck - and it is not known before hand - so a checkbox model for checking off who is there needs to be done... Hence the variable i for each unique person - which does sort itself out and insert properly... I'm trying to actually create a count so I know we have the right number of people counted on each truck to allow the insert... Because the code would allow say all 7 right now on 1 truck - when it should count 4 on one and 3 on other to be sure numbers are right.

Comment: I understand your intent.  Your code is not doing what you will hope.  If you know in advance that there were 4 people on Truck A and 3 on Truck B, those numbers have to be entered by a user.  Then you want to check to see if the number of people selected for Trucks A and B are 4 and 3 respectively.  Your code, quite simply, does not do that.